# Typescript - how to access the class declared through the namespace?

Tags: typescript, object, interface, namespaces

one fast question from a beginner. I am currently looking at the ways to reduce the number of 'imports' in my project and stumbled upon this tutorial - https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-useful-typescript-tips-for-angular

It suggests using namespaces to expose interfaces, like this

```
namespace ApiModel {
    export interface Customer {
        id: number;
        name: string;
    }

    export interface User {
        id: number;
        isActive: boolean;
    }
}
```

and this is how I should use the interfaces in the different file

```
export class MyComponent {
    cust: ApiModel.Customer; 
}
```

Looks good, but there is one thing I still dont understand. **How can I delare a new instance of Customer class and assign it some properties?** How can I assign properties to the object which is, as in this case, just a property of the Namespace?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you declared a `Customer` class that implements your `Customer` interface?

Comment: I tried, but didnt know how to extend the class if it's property is actually an another object. Could you advise?

Comment: Which property is an object? I only see data types... string, number and boolean.

Comment: According to the tutorial above, to use the interface, I need the following code: export class MyComponent { cust: ApiModel.Customer; usr: ApiModel.User }

Now I can create a new instance of MyComponent, but I cannot assign it any value like this - probably because I need to create also some instance of cust
var myComp = new JWTComponent; myComp.cust.id = "1";

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How can I declare a new instance of Customer class and assign it some properties?**
To declare a new instance of a class you first need to declare a class that implements your interface:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    export interface ICustomer {
        id: number;
        name: string;
    }
}

class Customer implements MyNamespace.ICustomer {
    id: number;
    name: string;

    constructor(id: number, name, string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

you can now instantiate `Customer` class.

**How can I assign properties to the object which is, as in this case, just a property of the Namespace?**
Namespace doesn't have properties. Classes and Interfaces do which may reside under your namespace. You can create a `customer` object which has the same properties as the interface:

```
const customer = {
    id: 1, name: "Mr. Bean"
} as MyNamespace.ICustomer;
```

The TypeScript type system is structural and not nominal, unlike C# or C++. That is why you can create `customer` since the object structure is the same.

Hope this helps!